# Alternative to shinyBS::popify with Bootstrap 4

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, shiny, popover

I'm using Bootstrap 4 in my Shiny app, with the help of the **bslib** package. Then the popovers made with `shinyBS::popify` do not work. Is there an alternative, or a way to make them work?

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "united"),
  popify(
    bsButton("pointlessButton", "Button", style = "primary", size = "large"),
    "A Pointless Button",
    "This button is <b>pointless</b>. It does not do <em>anything</em>!"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `spsComps`, it works with BS4

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
library(bslib)
library(spsComps)
ui <- fluidPage(
    theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "united"),
    bsPopover(
        bsButton("pointlessButton", "Button", style = "primary", size = "large"),
        "A Pointless Button",
        "This button is <b>pointless</b>. It does not do <em>anything</em>!",
        "bottom", html = T
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime, I switched to `shinyGizmo::modalDialogUI`. I didn't know **spsComps**.